# Decomposition of expectation values

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, conditional-probability

I have four (Bernoulli distributed) random variables, $S_1$, $P_1$, $S_2$, $P_2$, with the following properties:

- $S_1$ and $P_2$ are independent
- $S_2$ and $P_1$ are independent

all other combinations have correlations.

If I want to evaluate the expectation value
$$
E[P_1 P_2 S_1 S_2]
$$
is there any way to decompose it as correlators e.g.
$$
E[P_1 P_2], E[S_1 S_2], ...
$$

Can one use some kind of "conditioned" expectation values?

EDIT: each random variable can take two values e.g. +1, 0.

Comment: Have a look to [Isserlis' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isserlis'_theorem)

Comment: @JeanMarie thanks! unfortunately in my case I do not have normally distributed random variables, otherwise that would have been the perfect answer!

Comment: Do you know the parameter of the distributions?

Comment: @Prof.Shanku, let's assume yes

Comment: @m137 so basically you have to calculate $P(S1=1,S2=1,P1=1,P2=1)$...but i don't see how to do that unless you have some more information regarding the random variables

Answer (score 0):

Just expand the joint probability as usual
$$
\eqalign{
E[P_1,P_2,S_1,S_2]&=P(P_1,P_2,S_1,S_2)\\
&=P(P_1)P(P_2,S_1,S_2 | P_1)\\
&=P(P_1)P(P_2|P_1)P(S_1,S_2 | P_1,P_2)\\
&=P(P_1)P(P_2|P_1)P(S_1|P_1,P_2)P(S_2 | P_1,P_2,S_1)\\
&=P(P_1)P(P_2|P_1)P(S_1|P_1)P(S_2 | P_2,S_1)
}
$$
the last line removes the conditions that are not necessary to specify given the independence conditions. You can rewrite the probabilities in that line as conditioned expectation values if you wish.

Comment: The OP asks for the expectation of the **product** of these random variables